While using OpenTelemetry to log to AppInsights: type Trace is logged with severity Verbose
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API written in C#, and I'm using OpenTelemetry, without the collector, to log telemetry to AppInsights. I've achieved this using the AddAzureMonitorTraceExporter method, and it works as expected: I see the requests, and dependencies in AppInsights.
However, I also see that for every request, there is also a telemetry type trace that's being recorded. The severity of the telemetry is Verbose. I'd like to filter out these verbose traces. Here's a screen grab from AppInsights (modified for just the pertinent bits):

Here's what I've tried:
I tried to configure the log level in appsettings.json based on this post:
"Logging": {
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}

I added a filter based on the Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.AspNetCore README.md:
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
  .WithTracing(tracerProviderBuilder => tracerProviderBuilder
    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(options => options.Filter = ...);

I couldn't get the exact code snippet to work, but the above seemed to achieve the same purpose.
I added a processor that implements BaseProcessor<Activity> but this didn't seem to be involved in the telemetry type trace that was being logged.
Has anyone experienced this before? How do I set the log level for telemetry type trace?

Traces don't have log levels, it's a very different paradigm to logs and verbosity levels.
I imagine that's something that Application Insights is adding outside of the SDk, maybe even inside AppInsights itself.
The logging sections of appsettings.json does relate only ILogger data which does use the verbosity system of log levels.
